# Update BigQuery table from csv

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Suppose that we have a Table in BigQuery with the header like this:
id | name | price

and in this Table there are about 1 mln rows.

And, we have a csv-file with 100K rows with the same header: id | name | price
CSV is on the ftp-server.

BUT: several rows in CSV have the same id as in Table, and the others have new id

The task is: replace rows in the Table with the new ones from CSV by matching with id,
and append rows from CSV with new id.

For example, **in Table**:

```
id | name | price

0, str0, 1000

1, str1, 1500
```

**in CSV**:

```
id | name | price

0, str01, 1300

2, str2, 2500
```

after update we shoul have

```
id | name | price

0, str01, 1300 (updated)

1, str1, 1500

2, str2, 2500 (new)
```

Can I make it with Python libraries like google.cloud ??

Comment: You can use the `MERGE` statement https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use below steps to update data into BigQuery:

**Step-1: Copy CSV File to Cloud Storage**

```
$ gsutil cp data.csv gs://demo-bucket-0816
```

**Step-2: Create Table Definition File**

```
$ bq mkdef --autodetect --source_format=CSV "gs://demo-bucket-0816/data.csv" > myschema
```

**Step-3: Create External Table**

```
$ bq mk --external_table_definition=myschema bq_poc.ext_data
```

**Step-4.1: Merge Statement using BigQuery CLI**

```
$ bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 'MERGE bq_poc.target_data td USING bq_poc.ext_data ed ON td.id = ed.id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET price=ed.price WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, name, price) VALUES(ed.id, ed.name, ed.price)'
```

**Step-4.2: Merge Statement using Python**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

mergeQuery = """MERGE bq_poc.target_data td 
                USING bq_poc.ext_data ed 
                    ON td.id = ed.id 
                WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                    UPDATE SET price=ed.price 
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                    INSERT (id, name, price) VALUES(ed.id, ed.name, ed.price)"""
bigqueryClient = bigquery.Client()
sqlJob = bigqueryClient.query(mergeQuery)
sqlJob.result()
```